# rails has many through where query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

My model structure is set up like this,

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :conversation_statuses, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :conversation_statuses

  has_many :messages, :inverse_of => :conversation
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :conversation_statuses, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :conversations, :through => :conversation_statuses

  has_many :messages, :inverse_of => :user

end

class ConversationStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

I am trying to create a conversation only if the users don't have a conversation going. I have conversation set up so that more than 2 users can have a conversation. Right now my query is finding conversations including the user ids, but that may include conversations with large groups. My controller query looks like this,

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController


before_filter :set_user_ids_param, :only => :create

  def create

    @conversation = Conversation.joins(:users)
                                .where(:users => {:id => params[:conversation][:user_ids]})
                                .first_or_initialize

    @conversation.attributes = conversation_params

    if @conversation.save

      render :json => { :html => render_new_conversation_form }
      return
    end


    render :status => :bad_request, :json => {
      :html => render_conversation_form
    }

  end

  private
    def conversation_params
      params.require(:conversation).permit([
        :user_ids => [],
        :messages_attributes => [
          :content,
          :topic
        ]
      ])
    end

    def set_user_ids_param
      return if params[:conversation].blank?

      return if params[:conversation].blank? || params[:conversation][:user_ids].blank?

      params[:conversation][:user_ids] = params[:conversation][:user_ids].split(',')
      params[:conversation][:user_ids].push(current_user.id)
    end

    def render_new_conversation_form
      render_to_string({
        :partial => 'conversations/form',
        :locals => {
          :conversation => @conversation
        }
      })
    end

    def render_conversation_form
      render_to_string({
        :partial => 'conversations/form',
        :locals => {
          :conversation => @conversation
        }
      })
    end

end
```

and my form looks like this

```
= simple_form_for conversation, :html => {:class => 'conversation-form'} do |form|

 = form.input :user_ids, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:class => 'user-ids'}

  = form.simple_fields_for :messages do |message_fields|
    = render 'messages/fields', :message_fields => message_fields

  %button.button.radius.submit.no-margin
    Send Message

  %button.button.secondary.radius.cancel.no-margin
    Cancel
```

Any ideas on the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that will resolve your problem should be in class `ConversationStatus`, which will give you the `conversation_id` of the Conversation, if it exists.

You'll need two sets:

- `containing_all_users` are the conversations that contain all the users in `users_id`
- `with_extra_users` are the conversations that have more users than those in `users_id`

The conversation (if exists), is the result of the subtraction of those sets.

```
class ConversationStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation

  def self.find_between(user_ids)
    containing_all_users = group(:conversation_id)
        .where(user_id: user_ids)
        .having(['COUNT(user_id) = ?', user_ids.length])
        .pluck(:conversation_id)

    with_extra_users = group(:conversation_id)
        .having(['COUNT(user_id) > ?', user_ids.length])
        .pluck(:conversation_id)

    (containing_all_users - with_extra_users).first
  end
end
```

You'll get the conversation from the `Conversation` model. You should set the attributes on this method too:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversation_statuses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :conversation_statuses

  def self.find_between(user_ids, attributes = {})
    conversation_id = ConversationStatus.find_between(user_ids)
    Conversation.where(id: conversation_id).first_or_initialize(attributes)
  end
end
```

On the controller you will call it like this:

```
@conversation = Conversation.find_between(params[:conversation][:user_ids],
  conversation_params)
```

Comment: great thanks! For some reason the answer didn't pop up on my notifications.